# How can I make react native debugger my default on ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

Ive successfully installed Rn Debugger using command `brew update && brew install --cask react-native-debugger`.

However when I bring up the debugger menu on simulator, all I see is the option "Open Debugger" (which I understand is for flipper).

I want to use react-native-debugger with ios....how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to disable Hermes (which I had previously enabled so I could debug properly with Flipper)
`android/app/build.gradle` --> `enableHermes: false`
`ios/Podfile` --> `:hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],`